# send cron job notification by timezone php

Tags: php, cron, timezone, timezone-offset

I want to write a script that will send push notification to users' phone every day at 2 pm. But there are users from all over the world, so I need to send that notification at time depending upon the timezone of particular user, which I keep in DB like this 'GMT+4'.

I need to do this by Cron job. I have never used that, so I don't know how to write that script and make this work in PHP. Anybody can help me?

Comment: I guess, run the cronjob every hour and filter the correct users in your script with a mysqlquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple approach is to have a cron-job call a PHP script every 1 minute, and have it check the database for things that need to be done. If something needs done *now()*, then do it.

In *crontab* you can use something like this,

```
* * * * *   /usr/bin/php /path/to/my/script.php
```

And *script.php* can be like this

```
<?php
$ts = time();

// Run for up to 50 seconds
while($ts + 50 > time())
{
   ... SELECT id, time FROM Table WHERE time <= timeFromGMT(GMTvalue) ...
   if(returns a row){
     Send notification;
     Set a flag that notification is send;
   }
   sleep(5);       
}
```

***Note:*** Use some locking mechanisms to prevent multiple processes at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction**

*Skip to the "Solution summary" section below if you're only interested in the actual answer/solution.*

I realize this is an old question with an accepted answer and long inactivity (and quite frankly not that many views as of this writing), but I think this deserves a better answer because:

- The currently accepted answer to this question doesn't get into the nitty gritty. The answer doesn't elaborate the named (pseudocode?) mysql function "timeFromGMT" for instance, and what is required to make the program described in the original question actually work properly and as expected.
- This question almost covers my exact scenario, but it can be asked many different ways. There are a lot of existing Q&A's with similar (timezone related) subjects, but none I've found so far are as fitting as this one; a lot of the answers assume different conditions (such as date/time input from the user).
- I believe the answer to this question covers a wider area of situations than just the one described by the OP. I think it's safe to say that for a lot of people it's also not such a trivial task to work with timezones.

**A few things up front**

I've reformulated the question a bit to broaden it:

**How to make a PHP script (cron job) do something at a set users' local time, given only the users' timezone (id)?**

- The "given only the users' timezone id" part is essential. In a web apps where the users input scheduled tasks for example, you'd have a timestamp to work with.
  But if the user is for example only presented with an option such as "send me a notification each day" we don't have that information. So all we likely have is the users' timezone (id), and wether or not they've enabled the "do something every day" setting.
- The original poster of this question mentioned having the user "timezones" stored in a format such as "GMT +4", wether or not this is with daylight saving time accounted for isn't mentioned (or stored?) -- I would recommend to avoid this.
  I'd recommend storing the user's PHP [timezone (named) id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) instead (such as "Europe/Amsterdam"). These ids can be used in all of [PHP's date & time functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).
- Another general recommendation when dealing with timezones is to calculate everything from UTC, since daylight saving time does not affect it.
  So if you *do* have a web application where users input tasks at a specific date/time, store the UTC date/time (or PHP's UNIX timestamp returned from [time()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php), which is also always in UTC, even regardless of the timezone set with "[date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)" for example).
- In order to cover all different timezones, a cron job would have to run the php script atleast every 15 minutes. E.g. the timezone "Pacific/Chatham" is UTC +12:45 at the time of this writing. Creating the cron job itself is covered in many existing articles and should be easy to search for and set up.

**Solution summary**

In order for the cron job to do something at a specific time in the users' local time, we first have to know in which timezone(s) it is currently that given time.

If (like in the original question) we want to do something each day at 2 PM local user time, we could loop over all possible timezones (which we can retrieve with [DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php)), then check what time it is for each timezone currently and if it matches the given time (2 PM, or "14:00" in this example) we know the users who have that particular timezone set (and also the "do something every day" setting enabled) are the ones we need to select from the database. For the purpose of finding timezones where it is currently a given time, I created a custom function get_timezones_where_time_is().

*From the above follows the requirement that the cron job needs to run in every possible timezone offset from the time given to find all possible matching timezones. I.e. atleast every 15 minutes, and atleast on the time specified (2PM in this example).*

*This is an edge case, but get_timezones_where_time_is() must be called within the same minute of the specified time to get expected results. If the cron job would run at 12:00 server time for example, but get_timezones_where_time_is() only gets executed after a minute at 12:01, it ofcourse won't find any timezones anymore in the world where it is 14:00 at the moment (because at that point it's already 14:01 somewhere instead).*

**Solution**

This is an example script which you'd run with a cron job, see the comments in the code for more details. It should work in PHP 5 >= 5.2.0.

```
<?php
/* Just an example, since inluding files in a cron job can be counter intuitive */
set_include_path('/var/www/vhosts/example.com/');// this must be an absolute path, I recommended to the parent directory of your web/document root.
require_once 'config/config.php';// could contain the mysql login details

// Takes a time (hour and minutes) in the 24 hour clock format WITH LEADING ZERO'S, e.g. "14:00" or "04:00",
// Returns an array of timezone id's (from DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()) where it currently is that given time, or an empty array.
// Throws exception on false $time input parameter
function get_timezones_where_time_is(string $time)
{
  $time = explode(":", $time);
  if(!isset($time[0]) || !isset($time[1]))
  {
    throw new Exception('Function get_timezones_where_time_is() expects a time paramter in 24 hour format with leading zero\'s, such as "04:00".');
  }
  $ret = array();
  $timeHours = $time[0];
  $timeMinutes = $time[1];
  $timezoneIds = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
  foreach($timezoneIds as $key => $tzId)
  {
    $now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone($tzId));
    if($timeHours == $now->format('H') && $timeMinutes == $now->format('i'))
    {
      $ret[] = $tzId;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}

try
{
  // get timezone id's where it is currently the given time of the day
  $timezoneMatches = get_timezones_where_time_is('14:00');
  // if no timezones found where it is currently the given time, we have nothing to do
  if(!$timezoneMatches)
  {
    exit;
  }
  // we have atleast 1 found timezone where it is the given time of the day, so prepare and query the database
  $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
  {
    throw new Exception('mysqli connection error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
  }
  // just an example query, ofcourse
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE timezone IN ('".implode("', '", $timezoneMatches)."') AND send_daily_notification = 1";
  $selectUsers = $mysqli->query($query);
  if(!$selectUsers)
  {
    throw new Exception("There was probably an error in the query: ".$query);
  }
  while($user = $selectUsers->fetch_assoc())
  {
    // do something for each user, such as sending a notification
  }
  $selectUsers->close();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
  // logs to php ini defined error log file
  error_log('Cron job "send notification" failed with error message: '.$e->getMessage());
  // output error here for easier debugging when running script directly (e.g. from command line)
  echo 'Failed with error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

**Afterwords**

- The error handling and choice of mysqli is personal preference ofcourse, I did my best to include best practise to my knowledge and aimed it at the audiance I think visits StackOverflow. You should/would probably want to use [PHP PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) if you think you're every going to deal with different database systems instead, for example.
- On my test/development server [DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php) contains 425 timezones; the (custom) function get_timezones_where_time_is() with a given time completes in roughly 20 miliseconds when 50 timezones are found. In the given scenario the function ony needs to be called once.
- Checking against the actual current time in the given timezone with a [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object (in the loop in function get_timezones_where_time_is()) means we're also accounting for daylight saving time. PHP ini timezone settings or earlier calls to [date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) in the script for example shouldn't affect the results.
- I recommend to avoid picking a time which can be during a daylight saving time switch. E.g. get_timezones_where_time_is('02:00') can potentially do unexpected things, if the clock goes back from 03:00 to 02:00 the script will very likely 'run again' because it actually is that time again (I haven't tested).
- [DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php) might seem like (part of) a solution, but it contains historical timezone data and thus the same timezone id can appear in it multiple times with different offsets (see the currently most upvoted comment on the linked php manual page), that makes it unsuitable to get timezone id's by offset for example.
- I didn't [real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) the timezone ids because I regard them as trusted input. If a timezone id with quotes in it is ever introduced, the shown example database query will break.
- If like the OP you have only stored user timezones in a format as "GMT +4", and without wether or not this includes daylight saving time, it becomes a bit of a guessing game. I'd probably either loop over the timezone ids returned by my get_timezones_where_time_is() function, create a DateTimeZone object for each timezone and use DateTimeZone::getOffset() to get the GMT offset in seconds and correct for dst. Convert that offset into hours and then use that to query the database for users with timezones in the format like "GMT +4". If possible it would be best to fix the data problem.